# Load (part of) HTML page in a <div> using JS now produces Safari error: "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP"

Tags: javascript, load

This is for using an HTML imagemap to load text from another HTML file (in a div with class .show-info) into a side-div (class .sidediv).

The clicking place:

```
<area class="nohref" shape=rect coords="106, 226, 1002, 425" onClick="fillSideDiv('../PAGEExportSamples/Prototypesamples/Sampleaudio_noteA.html .show-info')" href="#">
```

The JS:

```
<script>
    function fillSideDiv(url) {
        $(".sidediv").load(url);
    };
</script>
```

This now only works when I upload all files onto my website—but it used to work locally, its intended use. There are three other "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP" answers on StackOverflow but none deals with this little issue.

Comment: why is ' .show-info' in the url ?

Comment: Not all of the HTML document is being read into the div. Only that part in my "main body" div, which I've assigned the class ".show-info." In other words, I'm using a class, rather than and id, to mark the text to read.